# Adding preprocessor to CL in command line and build *.sln by MSBuild

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, preprocessor, cl

I need to compile and build c++ project in command-line using `MSBiuld` without using vs2019 IDE, some preprocessors must be added by command-line!

for example, how to define `PO` preprocessor and run `MSBuild` to compile below code?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
#ifdef PO
    cout << "PO is defined";
#else
    cout << "PO not defined";
#endif
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [CL environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/cl-environment-variables%5C) any prepossessor can be defined by `/D`
for example

```
set CL=/DPO
MSBuild project.sln
```

To make sure that the last definition of prepossessors will applied without restarting cmd or commandline tool, use  `/t:Clean;Rebuild`

```
set CL=/DPO
MSBuild Project1.sln /t:Clean;Rebuild
```

Comment: A good learning. Thanks for sharing the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CL environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/cl-environment-variables) to set the [`/D` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/d-preprocessor-definitions).

For example, to define `PO`, you can do

```
SET CL=/DPO
```

on the command line before invoking MSBuild.

Just be sure to read those docs, because you'll probably need to use the number sign (`#`) instead of the equal sign (`=`) if you want to define a preprocessor constant with an explicit value. Also (depending on the context) the quotes (`"`) may need to be escaped (like `\"`) if you want to define a string constant.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, it is ok when your sequence is applied, but changing CL varibales dose not reflected in last build

Answer (score 1):

Actually, MSBuild command line can only transmit [msbuild properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019) into it rather than [msbuild items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2019#item-definitions) and metadatas.

[image]

And `PreprocessorDefinitions` is a metadata of `ClCompile` item.

The solution is that you should insert a msbuild property into `PreprocessorDefinitions` to transmit values from command line.

Add like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <POValue></POValue>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
     ....
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)$(POValue)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
     ....
    </ClCompile>

  ....

</ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

This is for `Debug|Win32` and you can add like this for each of **Configuration** and **Platform**.

[image]

**Then**, you can use `msbuild xxx\xxx.vcxproj -p:POValue=PO` command line to build under **PO** preprocessor.

**If** you do not want **PO**, you only do need to add `-p:POValue=PO` on the command line.

**And** if you have other preprocessors, you can modify the `PreprocessorDefinitions` like this:

```
<PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)$(POValue);$(OnePreprocessor);$(TwoPreprocessor)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I don't want modify project file and add such $POValue